# Searching for tags with synonyms leads to surprising behavior

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, search, tag-watching

When someone searches for `[itext] -[itextsharp]`, Stack Overflow replaces that query with `[itext] -[itext]`.

Context: I was looking for questions about itext, without questions specific to the C# version of the library.

I thought it was a bug at first, but then I realized that this behavior is due to the fact that `[itextsharp]` is a synonym of `[itext]`, hence it gets replaced.

- Should SO inform the user why his or her query was changed?
- Should `[itext] -[itextsharp]` be transformed into `[itext]`?

(Not sure if this is more of a bug report or a feature request)